# Custom Commands in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

How to make a custom ls command that echoes first n cubes to a txt file. How to make this command inside a .sh file that executes and the command is implemented.
Can we use the alias command?

Comment: Do you want to do math in a shell-script?  And calculate `1*1`, `2*2` ...`n*n`?

Comment: I want to define a custom command

Comment: How does this relate to the function of `ls`?

Comment: I want to change the ls command to do the above function instead of listing

Answer (score 2):

> How to make a custom ls command that echoes first n cubes to a txt file.

Please note that what you want to do as nothing to deal with `ls` command which is for listing files and directories....

To define a "custom" command,  you may:

- Define an alias into your shell if your command can be implemented just by using existing commands.
- Write a shell script and install it into a directory that is part of `${PATH}` (or run it by specifing the full path).
- Write C/Python/Perl/Whatever code, compile it (if needed) and just as for shell script, put it into a location from `${PATH}` or run it by specifying full path.

> How to make this command inside a .sh file that executes and the command is implemented.

Open a file with your favourite text editor, write the code, save it, give it the execution permission (`chmod +x <your .sh>`) and that's it.

> Can we use the alias command?

As said before, if what you want to do is already possible with a simple command-line, then yes. just put `alias <your_command_name>=<the command set to implement what you want>` into your favourite shell configuration file.